# How to maintain multiple branches for a primary key (col1) and a json datatype column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a design question where I know that JSON is the best option but still facing issues with implementation.

Requirement:

I need to store business entity information. Attributes are (registration_NO (primary key), Address, phone number (multiple phone numbers), directors (multiple people) etc.
It is due to the one-to-many between registration_number and (phone number, and directors), I decided to go with jsonb datatype.

there are 2 conditions.

1. phone number, directors may be added, removed etc.
2. any new changes to the records need approval. Until approved, the old values will be displayed.

Problems I am facing:
say for example:
current record: Regno: directors, record_status (did not show phone number on purpose)

```
              100: {John, Joe}, current; ok to display
```

when I add a new director, this entry must be a new branch of the registration# Primary key with status as "not yet approved" and therefore should not show up in queries.

```
              100: {john, joe, jane}, updated; not yet approved.
```

however, when I update the row, the old value of directors is getting overwritten.
When I insert with status as "update; not yet approved", then it inserts a duplicate record for the registration#.

Ideally, I would like to have 2 branches for registration# 100 ; one approved to show, and one not approved to show.

How should I manage this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Side note: The schema looks pretty static to me. So JSON is not "the best option". You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Comment: Blue Star and Sticky bit are absolutely correct: **Do not store JSON**. It is great for process to process communication, but  awful for storage. Store your data normalized then if needed you can export as JSON. See Postgres documentation on  [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH).

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: If your data has a predictable structure, you probably don't want to use a JSON column.

I would implement this with three tables. One table for the business entity, one for the phone numbers, and one for the directors. Something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE business_entity (
    registration_no uuid, 
    address text, 
    PRIMARY KEY(registration_no)
);

CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('added', 'deleted');

CREATE TABLE business_entity_phone_number (
    registration_no uuid, 
    phone_number text, 
    status status, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_business_entity_phone_number 
        FOREIGN KEY(registration_no) REFERENCES business_entity(registration_no)
);

CREATE TABLE business_entity_director (
    registration_no uuid, 
    director text, 
    status status, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_business_entity_director 
        FOREIGN KEY(registration_no) REFERENCES business_entity(registration_no)
);
```

The status columns are there to track changes. So if a new phone number is added, we mark that row as "added" until it's approved, and if a row is deleted we leave it in place but mark it as "deleted" until it's approved.

Then, in order to query our business entities, we need only leave out "added" rows:

```sql
SELECT 
    be.registration_no, 
    address, 
    (
        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(phone_number) 
        FROM business_entity_phone_number bepn
        WHERE be.registration_no = bepn.registration_no 
        AND COALESCE(bepn.status, 'deleted') != 'added'
    ) as phone_numbers, 
    (
        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(director) 
        FROM business_entity_director bed
        WHERE be.registration_no = bed.registration_no 
        AND COALESCE(bed.status, 'deleted') != 'added'
    ) as directors
FROM business_entity be
```

Things this solution does not fully deal with:

- Tracking changes to other fields in `business_entity` (it wasn't clear from the question if this is needed)
- Updates to phone numbers/directors (or is adding/deleting enough?)
- What happens when two users try to make conflicting changes?

Comment: Thanks @blue star. I have a comment and possibly an answer to my problem as I have been working at it.

I do not prefer the multiple tables option. This is how our initial design is. This adds complexity to the design and maintance and tomorrow when new attributes are added I have to start the design at the DB level, make API changes and a lot more.

Another reason, even if I know the structure the content may vary. For eg: phone numbers, and board+of+directors... keeping them in individual table is not ideal I think.

I came up with an answer for this problem.

Comment: Instead of keeping the record_status as a json attribute, I decided to make it part of the composite primary key

Since I only have 2 choices, a current row that is ok to display and the updated row which is going through approvals and not ok to display. 

Once approved, a trigger will fire that will copy the "not_ok_to_display" json data to "current" record and the changes will be visible.
and the "approval" for the not_ok_to_display row will be NULL again waiting for new updates and approvals once again.
I would like to hear if there are any comments to improve on this design.